# Laravel Eloquent Query Where IN statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do I convert this MySQL query to Laravel Eloquent Query:

> SELECT * FROM `service_package` WHERE price IN ('110010', 'Test 02', '11009')

Comment: Search docs for `whereIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `whereIn()` like:

1. Using `DB::table()`

```
$data = \DB::table("service_package")
               ->whereIn("price", ['110010', 'Test 02', '11009'])
               ->get();
```

2. Using Eloquent

```
$data = App\ServicePackage::whereIn("price", ['110010', 'Test 02', '11009'])
               ->get();
```

Here, make sure you have created model `ServicePackage` for the table `service_package`.